# Select with hasOne in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I have three models

```
Posts
Users
UserImages
```

In Posts I have

```
public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo(new User)->with('avatar');
}
```

In User I have

```
public function avatar() {
    return $this->hasOne(UserImage::class)->where('type', 1); //type 1 is avatar;
}
```

I call from Posts controller and I have screenshot below:

```
$posts = $this->model::select('*')->with('user')->get();
```

[image]

It returns too much information. I want to select something like thí

[image]

Is possible with hasOne and belongsTo ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can join the eager loading query to get the desired result:

```
$posts = $this->model::select('*')->with(['user'=>function($query) {
            $query->join('avatars', 'avatars.user_id', 'users.id')
                ->select(['users.id', 'users.name', 'users.userName', 'avatars.images_url']);
        }])->get();
```

to use 'avatar' relation you can use multi eager loading:

```
 $posts = $this->model::select('*')->with(['user'=>function($query) {
                $query->select(['users.id', 'users.name', 'users.userName'])
                ->with(['avatar'=>function($query){
                    $query->select(['user_id','images_url']);
                }]);
```

Comment: Thank you for your query. It is good but I defined hasOne(UserImage::class) in User model. There is no way to do with this instead of using join with query builder?
if only way as your answer so Laravel helper has no help in relationship?

Comment: I added condition ->where('avatars.type', 1), as your join method above, it returns null for user if user has no avatar?

Comment: yes, if you want otherwise, you can use leftJoin instead of join